# Is it wrong to use 'As equally significant as'?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I was preparing for IELTS and I used an online correction service, which corrected the following sentence I had used.

Original:

"Due to the monetary benefits brought by careers, working has become as equally significant as the other aspects of life hence creating a balance between work and pleasure has become a farfetched goal."

Corrected:

"Due to the monetary benefits brought by careers, working has become equally significant to the other aspects of life. Hence creating a balance between work and personal life has become a farfetched goal."

I want to confirm if the usage of "as equally significant as" is wrong in my original sentence. Is it because I use "as __ as" and "equally" together, which means the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As ___ as" = "equally ____"

so you can say "as awesome as me" or "equally awesome as me" but not "as equally awesome as me" (sounds redundant).

Comment: Just to add, "you are as equally awesome as me" means that I am "equally awesome," and you are **equally** equally awesome.